# If I change the CSS for the whole website rather than a specific component, would it still cause problems in the future update releases?

Tags: css, custom, navigation-menu

Basically, I need to use custom CSS override to modify a tile menu component and some other components, but there is this warning in the developers website:
[image]

How do I maneuver around this issue? Would it still cause challenges in the future if I changed the CSS for the whole website? Thanks.